# How do I render a commerce promotion coupon code on the order details?

Tags: theming, commerce

I want to show a coupon code used on an order details page, but cannot seem to render it on a templates. Here are some things I have tried so far...

```
{% for coupon in order_entity.coupons %}
  {{ coupon.target_id }}
  {{ coupon.code }}
  {{ drupal_entity('commerce_promotion_coupon', coupon.target_id) }}
  {{ drupal_field('code', 'commerce_promotion_coupon', coupon.target_id) }}
{% endfor %}
```

The only thing that works is {{ coupon.target_id }} and it just prints out the id as a number. I thought I could use Twig Tweak to load the entity and get it that way, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to inspect the ID variable to make sure it contains an ID not render array.
`{{ dd(coupon.target_id) }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved it ... (requires [Twig Tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak))

```
{% set coupon_entity = drupal_entity('commerce_promotion_coupon', coupon.target_id) %}
{{ coupon_entity['#commerce_promotion_coupon'].getCode }}
```